# Proximity Device API - Argument Exception on NDEF Publishing

Tags: c#, uwp, nfc, ndef

I'm tryng to write binary data using Windows Proximity Device API.

I can discover NFC tags and I can read NDEF messages from TAGs, writted at Android Phone.

But when I try to set up a PublishBinaryMessage, I always receive ArgumentException (Value does not fall within the expected range) when I use this messageTypes: 
"NDEF", "WriteableTag", or any other described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701129.aspx 
**except "Windows.someSubtype"**. But in this case, my TAG isn't writed.

I get ArgumentException with "NDEF.someSubtype", but the message is         "Message    "The parameter is incorrect.This ProximityDevice does not support the passed in messageType: NDEF.someSubtype"

The code:

```
//Does not work - Argument Exception - "Value does not fall within the expected range"
messageID = proximityDevice.PublishBinaryMessage("NDEF", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("lorem ipsum").AsBuffer(), MessageTransmittedHandler);

//Does not work - Argument Exception - "The parameter is incorrect"
messageID = proximityDevice.PublishBinaryMessage("NDEF.something", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("lorem ipsum").AsBuffer(), MessageTransmittedHandler);

//No Exception, but never writes on device.
messageID = proximityDevice.PublishBinaryMessage("Windows.something", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("lorem ipsum").AsBuffer(), MessageTransmittedHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input Buffer was wrong. In case of NDEF messages, the API docs say:

> The message contents are properly formatted NDEF records

So, using the ndef-nfc library from Andijac (https://github.com/andijakl/ndef-nfc), the binary message was properly published.